# How to get both PIPESTATUS and output in bash script

Tags: bash, pipe

I'm trying to get last modification date of a file with this command

```
TM_LOCAL=`ls -l --time-style=long-iso ~/.vimrc | awk '{ print $6" "$7 }'`
```

TM_LOCAL has value like "2012-05-16 23:18" after execution of this line

I'd also like to check PIPESTATUS to see if there was an error. For example if file does not exists, `ls` returns 2. But `$?` has value 0 as it has the return value of `awk`.

If I run this command alone, I can check the return value of ls by looking at `${PIPESTATUS[0]}`

```
ls -l --time-style=long-iso ~/.vimrc | awk '{ print $6" "$7 }'
```

But `$PIPESTATUS` does not work as I've expected if I assign the output to a variable as in the first example. In this case, `$PIPESTATUS` array has only 1 element which is same as `$?`

So, the question is, how can I get both `$PIPESTATUS` and assign the output to a variable at the same time?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do this:

```
TM_LOCAL=$(ls -l --time-style=long-iso ~/.vimrc | \
             awk '{ print $6" "$7 }' ; exit ${PIPESTATUS[0]} )
```

Then `$?` will be the return code from `ls`. This doesn't work if you need the return code from more than one of the pipe parts (but you could split the pipeline if the output isn't too large, as it is here).

Here's a rather expensive way of getting the full `PIPESTATUS` array and the output. Not very elegant, but haven't found anything else:

```
result=$(echo -e "a\nb\nc" | \
          ( cat ; exit 1 ) | \
          ( cat ; exit 42 ) ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]})
output=$(head -n -1 <<< "$result")
status=($(tail -n 1 <<< "$result"))
echo "Output:"
echo "$output"
echo "Results:"
echo "${status[@]}"
```

Which gives:

```
Output:
a
b
c
Results:
0 1 42
```

Comment: This work in my case, but I'm still curious about if there is a way to get complete pipestatus array and the output.

Comment: The head/tail parsing assumes the last line contains only statuses, which only works if previous output ends with a \n.  If you add a guaranteed \n between them — `echo; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]})` — it should be possible to parse unambigously.  I'm not certain but I think `output=$(head -n -1 <<< "$result" | head -c -1)` can work.  But perhaps it's becoming cleaner to "smuggle" the statuses out by some other channel, e.g. temp file, or file descriptor 3...

Answer (score 4):

Use `set -o pipefail` in `bash` to get the right-most non-zero exit code in a piped command sequence as `$?`. From `man bash`:

> If set, the return value of a pipeline is the value of the last (rightmost) command to exit with a non-zero status, or zero if all commands in the pipeline exit successfully.  This option  is  disabled by default.

Then you can simply access `$?`. Use `set +o pipefail` to disable again.

Answer (score 3):

The main problem with "what you expect" is that a command in backquotes is executed in a subshell; `$PIPESTATUS` exists there and the status returned fromm it follows the same rules as if you executed a single executable (or shell script).  The status of the backquote command is the rightmost (`awk`) status.

To implement what @[Daniel Beck](https://superuser.com/a/614065/32869) said, set the `pipefail` option in the subshell thusly:

`` TM_LOCAL=`set -o pipefail; ls -l --time-style=long-iso ~/.vimrc | awk '{ print $6" "$7 }'` ``

now the status stored in `$?` afterwards will be the status of `ls` (if non-zero).

However, I think an explicit `if [ -f ~/.vimrc ];`... test would be more readable.

You can't get output into a variable and `PIPESTATUS` returned without either a temporary file for the former, or marshalling the latter into a string.

Answer (score 2):

I assume the issue here is that PIPESTATUS goes away in its entirety as soon as you execute a command.  You can get the complete PIPESTATUS array in bash version 2 or above this way:

```
declare -a status
status=(${PIPESTATUS[@]})
```

Then access `${status[0]}`, `${status[1]}`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to check for the existence of your file before
getting its modification time with a call to `stat`. Since
`stat` returns slightly more than you want in the timestamp,
you can trim it using parameter expansion.

With GNU `stat` (e.g. on Linux), you could run:

```
[[ -f ~/.vimrc ]] && TM_LOCAL=$(stat -c '%y' ~/.vimrc 2>/dev/null)
TM_LOCAL=${TM_LOCAL%:*}  # Safe to do, even if stat fails
```

On Mac OS X and other BSD systems, `stat` syntax differs and can specify a time format:

```
[[ -f ~/.vimrc ]] && TM_LOCAL=$(stat -f '%Sm' -t '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' ~/.vimrc 2>/dev/null)
```

Comment: In what is now the GNU answer, you say the change to `$TM_LOCAL` is safe. It is only safe if you expected it not to have a prior value. Say the value was previously `2020-02-27 17:14` and there is no `~/.vimrc` file. You'd then have `2020-02-27 17`. I'd therefore chain those two lines together with an additional `&&` or (preferably since that's not so legible) use an `if` stanza.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to send email fron cron only if the exit status was not zero

The trick is that to get the stdin for the end of the pipeline you need to to put it in a subshell - but that seems to hide the PIPESTATUS value ...

test cron spits out some output and exits with 1 or 0 ..

```
./testcron | (test ${PIPESTATUS[0]} -ne 0 || mail -s "testcron output" paul)
```

UPDATE: the PIPESTATUS is not visible until the pipeline command is processes