# How do you use PIPESTATUS, tee and /bin/sh together?

Tags: linux, bash, pipe, exit-code

When I run

```
curl | tee test.txt; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}
```

I correctly see

> curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
>
> 2

But when I try to run exactly same command using '/bin/sh':

```
sh -c "curl | tee test.txt; echo \${PIPESTATUS[0]}"
```

I get

> curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
>
> sh: 1: Bad substitution

How we can resolve `Bad substitution` problem, please?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get both PIPESTATUS and output in bash script](https://superuser.com/questions/425774/how-to-get-both-pipestatus-and-output-in-bash-script)

Comment: @jww, do them work via `sh -c "<your above link answer's scripts here>"`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You solve it by not using `sh`.

The `PIPESTATUS` variable specifically, and the `${var[idx]}` *array* syntax in general, are features specific to the Bash shell. They do not exist in POSIX *sh*, and even shells that *do* have arrays might use a different syntax.

It just happens that some Linux distributions symlink their `/bin/sh` to Bash. Other distributions, however, symlink it to *dash*, Debian Almquist Shell. Both are compatible with POSIX *sh* scripts, but only Bash accepts the `${PIPESTATUS[…]}` syntax.

So if you want to use it, run `bash -c "…"` instead.

Comment: Because its part of the question to use `sh`. Better answer bellow, with a hack. Not a better "solution", though (I'll agree that a better solution is to avoid `sh`)

Answer (score 8):

Workaound for '/bin/sh' or busybox

```
status=0
eval ` { ls /dontexists || echo status="$?"; } | tee /dev/null`
echo "# status=${status}"
```

Trace :

```
busybox sh ~/bin/test.sh 
+ status=0
+ ls /dontexists
+ tee /dev/null
ls: /dontexists: No such file or directory
+ echo status=1
+ eval status=1
+ status=1
+ echo # status=1
# status=1
```

Comment: This will fail if ls succeeds. Then this will eval all the file names.

Answer (score 1):

Also 'bash -c' seems to have a problem with it when called from tcsh:

`bash -c "curl | tee test.txt; echo \${PIPESTATUS[0]}"`

> PIPESTATUS: Undefined variable.

This works for me from tcsh:

`bash -c 'curl | tee test.txt; echo ${PIPESTATUS[0]}'`

> curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information 
>   2

GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
called from tcsh 6.17.06

Comment: That's expected behaviour: single quotes do not cause variable interpolation. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash

Answer (score 0):

You probably ask this question, because you use the busybox shell that does not have the `PIPESTATUS` array. In that case, the only option will be to `set -o pipefail`. But if you are using one of the almost extinct shells that does not have `PIPESTATUS` or `-o pipefail`, then you may consider writing temporary files either for the intermediate output or the return value.